# Does the Facebook Pixel only work when an ad is clicked on?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I am new the whole Facebook Pixel thing....

I have put the Facebook Pixel code into the header of my WordPress site - that is not a problem.  But I was under the impression that the 'conversions' would only show up in the Ad Manager if the viewer was coming from an ad that was clicked on.

It appears that the Facebook Pixel Conversion reports are showing all traffic, regardless if they clicked an ad link or not.

Is this normal behavior?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
The facebook pixel analytic page shows all traffic,  regardless if they clicked an ad link or not.
What are we doing wrong.?